# How to get `grep` to emit the right side of 'URL=http://example.com'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I'm trying to `grep` the following file myfile.txt:

```
[Section]
URL=http://example.com
```

I want it to return everything after the `URL=`, so only `http://example.com`.

If I try any of the following, they do not work:

```
>grep -m1 -i 'url=' myfile.txt
URL=http://example.com
>grep -m1 -i 'http.+*' myfile.txt
URL=http://example.com
>grep -m1 -i -o 'http\.$' myfile.txt

>grep -m1 -i -o 'http\.*' myfile.txt
http
>grep -m1 -i -o 'http\.*$' 
>
```

How can `grep` emit everything to the right of the equals symbol?  It seems to refuse to match to the end of the line.  And this will fail if the address happens to be anything other than 'http' (such as FTP, etc.)

---

Additions:

- This is on Mabox (Manjaro, Arch) Linux.
- It might very well be possible with some specialized Mabox tool; however general GNU tools are assumed because the answer might apply to anyone else finding this question, such as on Alpine.  So I'd prefer an answer to be general, and not platform-specific.
- `grep` was chosen simply because it should be possible, and easily emits a full matched line.  `grep` claims to support regular expressions, so should be able to match to end-of-line.  If another command would work better and/or simpler, that is fine; `grep` does not have to be used.  But a standard command that works on the vast majority of Linuxes would be most helpful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `grep`, have you considered `sed`?

Given your sample input file, this command...

```
sed -n '/^URL=/ s/.*=//p' myfile.txt
```

Produces as output:

```
http://example.com
```

---

Or maybe `awk`:

```
awk -F= '/^URL=/ {print $2}' myfile.txt
```

---

The problem with `grep` in this instance is that it's primarily a tool for returning matched lines; it's not really meant for performing transformations on those matches.

The `-o` option is an interesting idea, but there's not really anyway to restrict it to match only the part after the `=` unless you prefilter the input like this:

```
grep '^URL=' myfile.txt | grep -o '[^=]*$'
```

Comment: Thanks larsks, for a concise and effectual answer while others were eager to -1 and close.

Answer (score 0):

This should give what's expected :

```
grep -Po 'URL=\K.*' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This is very platform-local; it's not just limited to GNU grep, but specifically GNU grep _compiled with the optional libpcre library_ (and there are sound reasons to leave that compile-time option turned off; [it's had security problems in the past](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=libpcre), and moreover, [PCRE is slow](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html))

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OP has tagged `linux` where default `grep` should be compiled with the libpcre library.

Comment: That's true on _some_ Linux distros, but not _all_ Linux distros. You don't get GNU grep on Alpine, f/e -- you have Busybox grep there, so it's not GNU at all in the first place there, much less GNU with optional dependencies.

Comment: Can you give an example where we can test ?

Comment: I just gave one -- alpine. It's a very popular Docker base image.

Comment: If you have a  NixOS system available, you could also use `nix-shell -p busybox -c busybox grep -Po 'URL=\K.*' myfile.txt`

Comment: ...over in the embedded-systems world one also sees alternatives like [Toybox](https://www.landley.net/toybox/) for folks uncomfortable with Busybox's GPL licensing; I've also seen attempts to reimplement coreutils (and/or busybox) in memory-safe languages to avoid the security risks involved with C. The world isn't limited to the big desktop-oriented distros of the world; there are lots of smaller, niche toolchains about that generally hew closer to standard-mandated minimal functionality.

Comment: Base `alpine` has not even `bash` which is tagged by OP

Comment: Sure, but it's pretty common for folks to install bash on top of alpine -- which adds bash, but _doesn't_ add GNU grep; which shell you have and which coreutils you have are entirely separate concerns.

Comment: OP didn't even mention docker, let alone alpine.

Comment: ...and they also didn't add their distro. _We don't know_, so we shouldn't assume. (Add a caveat like "on distributions using GNU grep with libpcre," to your answer, and this would all be moot).

Comment: There is little chance OP is in docker even less on alpine.

Comment: There's little chance that's their desktop distribution, sure, but we don't know they're writing software to run on their desktop. This is a variety of caution that strikes me as in keeping with Postel's Law: if we're teaching a practice, it should be a practice that works as many places as possible unless we're going to explicitly describe the boundaries around its applicability. And it's not _hard_ to describe the circumstances where this answer applies; why spend time arguing vs amending to do so?

Comment: Even though this didn't work for me, I still +1'd for effort of trying.

Comment: @rdtsc I'm curious to know your environment. Could you possibly post the output of the commands `cat /etc/os-release` and `grep --version` ?